# Как закрыть основную форму при переходе на дочернюю и обратно?

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю школьный проект, проблема в том, что при нажатии на определенную кнопку с основной формы нужно переходить на дочернюю, не особо понимаю как это реализуется, чтобы открыть форму по нажатию, я создаю новый объект типа формы и скрываю основную форму

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 Tasks1Remark = new Form3();
            Tasks1Remark.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Но после мне нужно закрыть дочернюю форму и перейти на основную, метод hide() скрывает её, но  она всё равно висит в процессах.
Как мне полностью закрыть дочернюю форму сохраняя возможность открыть её заново если понадобится?

Comment: Попробуйте this.Hide(); поставить перед Tasks1Remark.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно было быть просто

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 Tasks1Remark = new Form3();
    this.Hide();
    Tasks1Remark.ShowDialog(this);
    this.Show();
}
```

Еще так можно

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 Tasks1Remark = new Form3();
    Tasks1Remark.FormClosed += (s, e) => this.Show();
    this.Hide();
    Tasks1Remark.Show();
}
```

Дочернюю закрывайте как обычно. Если она нужна снова, создавайте заново так же как в первый раз.