# Как контролировать взаемодействие пользователя с Windows формой в С#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Всем привет! Я работаю над созданием симулятора автомата по обработке заказов в McDonald's.
Возникла проблема с тем как контролировать взаемодействие и активность пользователя с/на формой(форме). Задача состоит в следующем: "Если пользователь никаким образом не взаемодействует с формой то есть ничего не нажимает и такое прочее то через определенный промежуток времени вывести на екран сообщение о том что заказ пользователя в скором времени будет удален если он не проявит какой либо активности или взаемодействия с формой" Как контролировать время понятно(через переменную типа Timer, эта переменная должна быть статичной) но вот только как контролировать взаемодействие пользователя с формой(нажатия кнопок или что-то подобное) я не могу придумать.

Заранее благоден тому кто напишет шаблон кода на языке С# который решит эту проблему :)

Приложу еще кусок кода с моей формы(для максимальной понятности ситуации)

Код с формы Form1.cs(это домашняя страница):

```
using System;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.Component.Model;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
namespace McDonald_s 
{
     public partial class Form1: Form 
     {
          public Form1()
          {
             InitializeComponent();
          }
          private void OrderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             Form2 form2 = new Form2();
             form2.Show(); // отобразить форму меню(там где надо данную операцию провернуть)
             this.Hide(); // спрятать текущую форму после нажатия на кнопку 
          }
     }
}
```

Код для формы заказа(Form2.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Component.Model;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace McDonald_s
{
     public partial class Form2: Form 
     {
         public Form2()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             this.button1.Visible = false; // кнопка которая отвечает за товар в выбраной пользователем категории 
             this.button2.Visible = false; // кнопка которая отвечает за товар в выбраной пользователем категории 
         }
         private void BurgerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArds e)
         {
               this.button1.Visible = true;
               this.button2.Visible = true;
               this.button1.Text = "Big Mac";
               this.button2.Text = "McChicken";
         }
// Далее еще 4 кнопки с похожим кодом 
     }
}
```

В какой секции Form2.cs я должен прописать код для даной операции?

Дополнительная информация:
На форму Form2 добавлены такие элементы управления:
ToolStrip,
Panel,
Button.

Внутри ToolStrip добавлено 5 кнопок(toolstripbutton) и 1 toolstriplabel

Если будет нужно докину еще сюда скриншот.

Спасибо :)

Comment: У вас неймспейс разный в первом и втором блоке кода

Comment: Это я уже поменял. Теперь все правильно

Comment: А как вы из 2 формы в первую возвращаться собрались? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1464926/373567

Comment: Запустили таймер и считайте раз в секунду до 30, при нажатии на любую кнопку сбрасывайте счетчик на 0. Если до 30 дошло, останавливайте таймер выдавайте предупреждение, после чего закрывайте форму.

Comment: Добавьте ко всем кнопкам (программно) обработчик Click, в котором и делайте сброс счётчика

Comment: А можно пожалуйста шаблон кода и где оглашать статичную переменную Timer? Сразу же после открытия формы Form2.cs?

Comment: Не сильно понимаю каким образом этот  обработчик нажатия написать. Можно пожалуйста пример кода